# Git ignore syntax: how to ignore from root?

Tags: git, gitignore

I put .gitignore in the root directory `A`. The subtree is the following:

```
A/B/bin
A/C/bin
A/D/E/bin
A/F/G/bin
```

All `bin` are folders. I want to ignore all their content and subdirectories.

By writing this line in .gitignore

```
bin/
```

will they be all ignored?

Comment: Use `bin/` instead. Also, you could simply try it out…

Comment: sorry, I wanted to write bin/

Comment: thanks, I found the answer in the duplicate